# Memory allocation performance

Tags: c

```
int a[1000];
int *c;

void foo(void)
{
     int b[1000];
     memcpy(b, someConstArray, 1000);
     c = (int *)malloc(sizeof(b));
     memcpy(c, b, 1000);
}

void bar(void)
{
     memcpy(a, someConstArray, 1000);
     c = (int *)malloc(sizeof(a));
     memcpy(c, a, 1000);
}
```

I know this has been asked quite a number of times, but I need to know what the performance difference between auto allocation vs static allocation, e.g. `a` vs `b`, in relative to each other. Does declaring the `a` this way take performance hit because of **locality**?

Compile in gcc for embedded systems.

**PS: I am aware that it is a redundant and useless function. The main question is how does the variable allocation affects performance**

Comment: Sorry my mistake, quick cut and paste thingy

Comment: the redundant `memcpy` is incomparably larger performance hit than the auto variable allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>In `char* foo(void)` you return an invalid pointer, because `b` ceases to exist when you exit the function.</strike>

Both allocations have the same performance <strike>, it's just the way you use them is incorrect</strike>.

`b` is allocated on the stack when the function `foo` is being called (the performance is of simply changing the value of the stack pointer). It's deallocated when `foo` is done (by changing the stack pointer, again).

`a` is allocated somewhere (global, I'm guessing, or on stack in some other context), and there's no performance hit there as well.

If you need to allocate memory within your function that should be given to the caller (as in your `foo`) - then the allocation should be *dynamic* - using `malloc` (or `new` if C++). Then there's indeed a performance hit, depending on the relevant memory manager performance.

Comment: I don't thing that other than the first paragraph, my answer should change in any way. There's no difference (performance wise) between the "static" global and the "auto" local allocations (unless you're so sensitive that changing the stack pointer is considered a performance hit, but then the function call itself is more costly anyway).

Comment: "...both are auto allocations". Not really. "Auto allocation" is normally an informal way to refer to auto[matic] storage duration, which is specific to local objects only. `a` has static storage duration, not auto.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Hoping for more input from others

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "it depends". There is no difference in memory allocation cost of a &b. Both have same cache locality properties for the memcpy.

However, You do have a trade-off between using stack space vs using data section.

Cost of allocating space on stack is really same, whether it is one local variable or a 1000 byte array. You just decrement stack pointer by larger number when you set up its stackframe.
b is part of program image and allocated at program load time.

If foo gets called repeatedly you might run into stack size limitation. On the otherhand since a is global, you can use an additional flag and copy into it only once and reuse a.

Comment: "Cost of allocating space on stack is really same, whether it is one local variable or a 1000 byte array. " Note this is not true with virtual memory systems, as stack growing can cause page faults, as the memory can be reserved only and needs to be committed. Therefore if you grow stack more than one page, it is slower then growing one page or less. Cf. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100775/en-us?fr=1